# Setting custom depth in tidyr spread

Tags: r, tidyr

Is it possible to set a limit to the amount of columns `tidyr::spread` creates that is *less* than `biggest_group_size`?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear about the greater than the `biggest_group_size`.  If we want to have to have columns with `NA` or `""`, use the `drop = FALSE` argument in `spread` after changing the 'id' to `factor` with extra `levels` specified

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(user_id) %>%
   mutate(id = paste0("pred_", row_number()), 
          id = factor(id, levels = paste0("pred_", 1:4))) %>%
   spread(id, pred, drop=FALSE, fill = "")
```

Comment: What I meant was to limit the amount of spread to be `N`, where `N` < `biggest_group_size`. I'm using this for a holdout period where I arrange first by `date` and then want only the first `N` observations to be spread out

Comment: @NickResnick  Please include a small example and expected output in your post for better understanding.